# How to fix segmentation fault when printing linked list?

Tags: c, printing, linked-list, segmentation-fault

When attempting to print my linked list of students, I am given a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". When I print the list by hard coding:

`

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    printf("%s, %s\n", head->pStudent->last, head->pStudent->first);
    head = head->next;
}
```

`

(3 nodes were created.) It works! When I try to print it like this:

`

```
while (head != NULL){
    printf("%s, %s\n", head->pStudent->last, head->pStudent->first);
    head = head->next;
}
```

`

It gives me the segmentation error.

I've tried `while (head->next != NULL){...}`

I've tried doing it in main instead of calling `print_list(head);`

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    typedef struct student{
        char *first;
        char *last;
    } student_t;

    typedef struct node{
        student_t *pStudent;
        struct node *next;
    } node_t;

    void addToStart(node_t ** head, student_t *student);
    void print_list (node_t * head);
    student_t *newStudent();

    int main(){
        node_t *head;
        student_t *studentOne = (student_t *) malloc(sizeof(student_t));
        student_t *studentTwo = (student_t *) malloc(sizeof(student_t));
        student_t *studentThree = (student_t *) malloc(sizeof(student_t));

        studentOne->first = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
        studentOne->last = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

        studentTwo->first = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
        studentTwo->last = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

        studentThree->first = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
        studentThree->last = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

        studentOne = newStudent();
        addToStart(&head, studentOne);

        studentTwo = newStudent();
        addToStart(&head, studentTwo);

        studentThree = newStudent();
        addToStart(&head, studentThree);

        print_list(head);

        printf("Then you will enter 3 students names that will be added to the end of the list\n");

        return 0;
    }

    void addToStart(node_t ** head, student_t *student){
        node_t *new = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));

        new->pStudent = student;

        new->next = *(head);
        *(head) = new;
    }

    void print_list (node_t * head){
        while (head != NULL){
            printf("%s, %s\n", head->pStudent->last, head->pStudent->first);

            head = head->next;
        }

    }

    student_t *newStudent(){
        student_t *new = (student_t *) malloc(sizeof(student_t));
        new->first = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
        new->last = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

        printf("Enter first name of student: ");
        scanf("%s", new->first);
        printf("Enter last name of student: ");
        scanf("%s", new->last);

        return new;
    }
```

Expected results:

```
    Enter first name of student: 1
    Enter last name of student: 1
    Enter first name of student: 2
    Enter last name of student: 2
    Enter first name of student: 3
    Enter last name of student: 3
    3, 3
    2, 2
    1, 1
```

Actual results:

```
    Enter first name of student: 1
    Enter last name of student: 1
    Enter first name of student: 2
    Enter last name of student: 2
    Enter first name of student: 3
    Enter last name of student: 3
    3, 3
    2, 2
    1, 1
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You are allocating __one__ character for the student name, but you treat it as a string. A string has a _terminating null character_ so a name of `"1"` still needs _two_ characters.

Comment: With `studentOne = newStudent();` you __overwrite__ `studentOne`. But you had just allocated memory to it with `malloc`. That memory is now _lost_.

Comment: In that case, could I leave out all the mallocs in main since in the method newStudent() it allocated memory?

Comment: Yes, you can leave them all out in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have this code, the last node on the list will point to what you have your `head` variable as when you first do the `addToStart`. But `head` is not  initialized:

```
node_t *head;
```

Properly initialize it so the loop will terminate correctly:

```
node_t *head = NULL;
```

You also only have 1 `char` worth of memory for your strings. That's not enough for anything else than an empty string. Try this instead:

```
new->first = malloc(32); // memory for 31 chars plus null terminator
new->last = malloc(32);

printf("Enter first name of student: ");
scanf("%31s", new->first); // read a maximum of 31 chars
printf("Enter last name of student: ");
scanf("%31s", new->last);
```

Furthermore, you're allocating memory for the students and strings twice, leaking memory in the process. Remove those redundancies and do this instead:

```
student_t *studentOne = newStudent();
student_t *studentTwo = newStudent();
student_t *studentThree = newStudent();

addToStart(&head, studentOne);
addToStart(&head, studentTwo);
addToStart(&head, studentThree);
```

You're also not freeing any memory anywhere, so I assume you're going to write a function to clean up the list later. With these changes, the program looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct student {
    char *first;
    char *last;
} student_t;

typedef struct node {
    student_t *pStudent;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

void addToStart(node_t ** head, student_t *student);
void print_list(node_t * head);
student_t *newStudent();

int main() {
    node_t *head = NULL;
    student_t *studentOne = newStudent();
    student_t *studentTwo = newStudent();
    student_t *studentThree = newStudent();

    addToStart(&head, studentOne);
    addToStart(&head, studentTwo);
    addToStart(&head, studentThree);

    print_list(head);

    printf("Then you will enter 3 students names that will be added to the end of the list\n");

    return 0;
}

void addToStart(node_t ** head, student_t *student) {
    node_t *new = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    new->pStudent = student;

    new->next = *(head);
    *(head) = new;
}

void print_list(node_t * head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%s, %s\n", head->pStudent->last, head->pStudent->first);

        head = head->next;
    }

}

student_t *newStudent() {
    student_t *new = (student_t *)malloc(sizeof(student_t));
    new->first = (char *)malloc(32);
    new->last = (char *)malloc(32);

    printf("Enter first name of student: ");
    scanf("%31s", new->first);
    printf("Enter last name of student: ");
    scanf("%31s", new->last);

    return new;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense. I've made the necessary changes but unfortunately I still get the segmentation fault.. It reads through the whole list and then boots out. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: That's strange. I posted my version that works fine when I run it.

Comment: yes, actually when I compiled it for the second time, it worked! Thanks!